# Calculating partial hash collisions in openCl

Tags: hash, opencl, sha, hash-collision

I would like to find 2 SHA-256 hashes of 2 strings (both of which start with "helloworld" and then have a number of random ascii characters following) where the first n characters of the hashes match, with n being as large as possible.

for example:

```
String 1 = helloworld\V.T  ao>
String 2 = helloworld EF{B -QMl
Hash 1 = JRFqsbBDZBUx9Ot0LviMEr6rAdKmUai/kx8HD0EskxE=
Hash 2 = JRFnMO6jm0hzdZ+jYZybNl9yVnPl9g5Y0vlz0Rf/6UE=
```

the first three characters of the hashes match.

Currently I am using java and MessageDigest for this which is slow, so I was thinking if i could use my GPU and openCl it could run the program much faster, however i know nothing about openCL or how i would go about coding something like this.

Does anyone know of an existing tool which could do this, or maybe some code?

Comment: How long are they usually and how many of them to check for collision? If there is only two and they are megabytes long, better on cpu. If they are short like less than several hundred bytes and there are thousands of these, better on gpu.